# Page not being reloaded on form Submit angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I managed to create a form in an Angular 5 , my question is how can I reload the page after user submits the form.

I need the page to be reloaded so the new added element would displayed in the datatable, which is getting the existing elements (using Async Subscribe from HTTP client method) from the DB

So this is what I need to do:

1. User fills form
2. POST query => my API (response OK)
3. Notification Displayed
4. At that time I need to find a way to
       reload the page or to update the existing Datatable

This is the Form Code:

```
    <form [formGroup]="BillForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
........
...............

    <div class="ml-auto">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd" name="finish" value="Confirm"
               [disabled]="BillForm.invalid">

    </div>
</form>
```

now this is the Onsubmit method :

```
  onSubmit() {
        var newBill = this.BillForm.value;
        newBill.CreatedAt = new Date();
        console.log(newBill);
        this.billservice.getCustomerId()
            .subscribe(
                res1 => {
                    console.log('this.BillService.getMonitorId', res1['Customer_id']);
                    this.billservice.getMonitorId(res1['Customer_id'])
                        .subscribe(
                            result => {
                                this.billservice.addBill(result['Monitor_id'], newBill)
                                    .subscribe(
                                        res => {console.log(res);
                                            if (res['result'] === 'Bill Added Successfully') {
                                                this.showNotification('bottom', 'right', 'success');
                                            }}
                                    );
                            });
                });
    }
```

It's working perfectly I just need to make better for the user , now it just addds the element to the table but I need to reload manually to see the change on table

This is how I am getting the data for the dataTable :

this.BillService.getCustomerId()
            .subscribe(
                res1 => {
                    console.log('this.BillService.getMonitorId', res1['Customer_id']);
                    this.BillService.getMonitorId(res1['Customer_id'])
                        .subscribe(
                            result => {

```
                            this.BillService.getBills(result['Monitor_id'])
                                .subscribe(res => {
                                    this.dataTable = {
                                        headerRow: ['#', 'Amount', 'Created at', 'From', 'To', 'Payment Status', 'Payment Date', 'Actions'],
                                        dataRows: res['result'][0]['Bills']
                                    };
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                        self.initTable();
                                    }, 10); });
                        });
            });
```

and in the view :

```
                                <tr *ngFor="let row of dataTable.dataRows">
                                    <td>{{row.Amount}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.CreatedAt | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.From | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.To | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
```

Comment: you might have an issue with `this` in the subscribe functions. I would look at that to see if that is the issue. To fix that you could try doing a `.bind(this)` at the end of the function or creating a `let this2 = this` before the `this.billservice.getCustomerId` and use `this2` in the subscribe functions

Comment: `this` inside a lambda is the same as `this` that encloses the lambda.

Comment: Where's your code for the table? There usually is no need to ever "reload" the page. Depending on your specific table, you may need only to update an object that represents the data source.

Comment: I suggest creating a sample demo at stackblitz.com for this.

Comment: @frod_junior. when we create a subscription of a httpClient.get, DON't mean that a change in our database will make the change was showed in the view. (I sometime say that a httpClient.get is an observable that only execute onetime). So, or you subscribe another time to the get the data when you change the data base, or you change manually the array, or a change of the database return all the data

Comment: I added the code of my dataTable and how the data is being displayed